# making rows of buttons using css

Tags: css

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to space out 6 buttons. I want is so that three of the buttons are at the top, while the other 3 are below the top row. So basically it would be two separate rows of aligned buttons.

I've gotten answers on a previous post like this but I forgot to include that I need to do it only using css, because html tags won't work.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Why can you not use HTML? CSS just styles and does stuff to currently existing HTML, so I don't see why you can't use it?

Comment: If you need some CSS code, so please show your HTML code, otherwise the answerers of course will give you **their own HTML code**.

Comment: That's why I don't understand what needs to be done. I'm an inexperienced coder but the all that we are using right now is java for the text of the button, and the button consist of only css. I already tried using html tags but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to tell us what you are building/using to build it.  It doesn't seem to be a webpage... is it a Java application? Android?

Comment: It's a legend for a forum. I made the buttons from css using the code I found in the skin. Then I made some JavaScript to put words on the buttons. I'm not sure if the html isn't working because it's a legend, but I've tried to div it using a html page and it didn't work. The forum also restricts me from using any html tags in the css itself.

Comment: You can not *make* anything with CSS. All CSS does is style elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div>
    <button>one</button>
    <button>two</button>
    <button>three</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button>one</button>
    <button>two</button>
    <button>three</button>
</div>
```

or

```
<button>one</button>
<button>two</button>
<button>three</button><br />
<button>one</button>
<button>two</button>
<button>three</button>
```

or

html

```
<div id="onebox">
    <button>one</button>
    <button>two</button>
    <button>three</button>
</div><br />
<div id="twobox">
    <button>one</button>
    <button>two</button>
    <button>three</button>
</div>
```

css

```
#onebox{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
#twobox{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
```